# When calculating NPV, why is it wrong to increase the discount rate to compensate for risk?

Tags: investing, calculation

I am calculating the Net Present Value (NPV) for my investments. I used a higher discount rate for the more risky investments. However, the "Common pitfalls" section of the [Net present value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_present_value) article on Wikipedia says this:

> - Another common pitfall is to adjust for risk by adding a premium to the discount rate. Whilst a bank might charge a higher rate of interest for a risky project, that does not mean that this is a valid approach to adjusting a net present value for risk, although it can be a reasonable approximation in some specific cases. **One reason such an approach may not work well can be seen from the following: if some risk is incurred resulting in some losses, then a discount rate in the NPV will reduce the effect of such losses below their true financial cost.** A rigorous approach to risk requires identifying and valuing risks explicitly, e.g., by actuarial or Monte Carlo techniques, and explicitly calculating the cost of financing any losses incurred.

Questions:

- Why can't I use a higher discount rate for valuing investments that are more risky?
- I don't understand the bold text. In particular: "if some risk is incurred resulting in some losses, then a discount rate in the NPV will reduce the effect of such losses below their true financial cost". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I use a higher discount rate for valuing investments that are more risky?

It doesn't say you *can't*, it just gives some drawbacks, and may not be as simple as adding an arbitrary risk premium. It's certainly common to use a discount rate from other investments of *equivalent risk* to calculate NPV.  Determining "equivalent risk" may be difficult and may not be fully encapsulated by a discount factor, but it's not altogether wrong.

> "if some risk is incurred resulting in some losses, then a discount rate in the NPV will reduce the effect of such losses below their true financial cost". What does this mean?

The reference to Monte-Carlo makes me think that the author is referring to a more probabilistic view of risk like Value At Risk (VaR). VaR tells you the maximum you can expect to lose with a certain probability (typically 95% or 99%). It's not saying that accounting for risk in the discount factor is *wrong*, only that it's not a *complete* view of risk. Every measure of risk (discount rate, IRR, VaR) has its strengths and weaknesses, and should be look at at parts of a whole rather than in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

The discount rate is the your gain in a risk-free alternative. It is independent from the risk of your investment.

I would take the uncertainty in future cash-flow into account by creating multiple scenarios with multiple probability level, and calculate with the expected value.